# Angular date pipe is displaying the incorrect date

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I got this date `2021-10-08T23:47:34.000Z` from the server and anytime i used the angular date `pipe` on it, it displaying `Oct 9, 2021` instead of `Oct 8, 2021`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Date</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{ element.created_at | date }}
      </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular's [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) uses locale to display the date, which means it changes it based on the user's timezone.

You can specify the timezone at the end of the pipe.

```
{{ element.created_at | date:'mediumDate':'UTC' }}
```

Comment: I don't really understand how `UTC` solves the problem. Can you please explain better?

Comment: If your backend stores dates at `UTC` timezone and you treat the date on frontend as `UTC` (read: the same timezone of your backend ) it will not apply any offset from the timezone.

Comment: How do i know if my backend stores the date as `UTC` or any other format?. i am using `sequelize`, `mysql` and `nodejs` for my backend.

Comment: It's not the format but the timezone. Unless you specifically change it for some reason, it's `UTC`.